# Rcpp package seems to install incorrect version of function

Tags: r, rcpp

I am working on an Rcpp package, and am seeing that changes to the source are not reflected in the output of the called function. I am installing the package with:
R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source

The function I'm working on was generating incorrect data, and while debugging I could find no reason for it or get the generated data to change. I also found that print statements I added weren't showing up on the console. I tried forcing the function to raise an error, and forcing the returned data to a constant value, but neither changed the behavior. I also tried:

- installing the tarball created by R CMD BUILD
- deleting the installed package folder from my PC and rebuilding
  Neither produced different results.

When I build the same function with sourceCpp() it runs fine; all my changes are reflected and the returned data is correct. It's just with installing the package that it doesn't work right. Does anyone have experience with similar issues?

### Update

In the project, I have the following function in src/RcppFunctions.cpp

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List Rcpp_svd_dense(Eigen::MatrixXd& A_, const unsigned int k) {
  RcppML::svd<Eigen::MatrixXd> m(A_, k);
  
  // set model parameters
  m.tol = 1e-9;
  m.maxit = 100;
  
  m.fit();
  
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("u") = m.matrixU(),
                            Rcpp::Named("d") = m.vectorD(),
                            Rcpp::Named("v") = m.matrixV(),
                            Rcpp::Named("tol") = m.fit_tol(),
                            Rcpp::Named("iter") = m.fit_iter(),
                            Rcpp::Named("mse") = m.fit_mse(),
                            Rcpp::Named("best_model") = m.best_model());
}
```

svd.fit() is the function that I have been having problems with. Additionally this R wrapper is defined in R/svd.R:

```
svd <- function(data, k){
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  
  model <- Rcpp_svd_dense(data, k)
}
```

When I load these files to a notebook with `source()` and `sourceCpp()`, the fit function works as expected. However, when installing the package and loading it with `library()`, it doesn't run as expected. The returned matrices have the wrong size, and the returned list doesn't contain all elements (only 'u', 'v', and 'd').

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  We will try to help you as best as we can but in order to do so we would really welcome a [minimally complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you please try to provide one?  Often these are problems of 'work flow' and by working on a example you even stumble upon the issue yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added some more detailed information. I'm not sure what exactly is helpful for this issue. Also I'm not sure if it could be reproduced based on code snippets, or is an issue with my system. To install the project, I use the 'install' button in the build window

Comment: Again, there is nothing we can do with having something _reproducible_. It's just guesswork: maybe a local copy (from `sourceCpp()` ?) shadows the package function.  But nobody can tell.  We need something reproducible.  See the link in my comment from two hours ago.

Comment: A quick guess is that compilation does not proceed because there are old `.o` and `.so` files in your `src` directory. To check this, try removing those and then rebuilding the package again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately deleting the .o/.so files from src didn't fix it. I'm working on trying to break down a copy of the package that has just the code I've contributed and am having issues with, but it's taking some time. I'll add an update if I find anything more helpful there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help solving this, I figured out a couple of issues with my setup:

1. I unknowingly had another function with the same name loaded from a different package
2. I didn't realize that `devtools::document()` had to be run in order for the build to actually export a function, so my own version was not available in the environment

After renaming my function and running document, the issue is fixed.